The British used to (still?) classify their guns by weight in pounds rather than caliber. Was that a constant across shell types?
We just had a question about a 1 pdr (37mm).  The 6 pdr is a 57mm and the 17 pdr in the Firefly was a 76mm.
So, far, so good.  It's even not too difficult to follow the progression:  it's roughly based on the cube of the diameter.
My question is however:  is the weight of the projectile constant across shell types?  I would expect an HE round with fragmentation capability to differ significantly from armor piercing round (and that's before we get into sabot rounds, which came much later).  What did they use as a reference?
In addition, this is really a long standing tradition, going way back to naval guns of the 18-19th century which were solid round shots.  This continuity makes me wonder if they even weighed modern shells, or were extrapolating from the calibers of older, round, solid shots.
I know, I know, it doesn't matter all that much.  But it has always intrigued me in with regards to the use of this, odd-sounding, classification scheme.
p.s. Is it just the shot that's getting weighed?  Or does it include the propellant and shellcase?
p.p.s.  Yes, the British do seem to have done away with this approach, starting sometime around the introduction of the L7 105mm gun on the Centurion MBT, in 1958.

The Royal Ordnance L7, officially designated Gun, 105 mm, Tank, L7, is the basic model of the United Kingdom's most successful tank gun. It is a 105 mm L/52 rifled design by the Royal Ordnance Factories, intended for use in armoured fighting vehicles, replacing the older QF 20-pounder (84 mm) gun mounted on the British Centurion tank


Just to complicate matters, early shell firing weapons (esp. mortars & field howitzers) were classified by their calibre (in inches) rather than by weight of shot.

Lots of shells get classified in inches, starting with Dirty Harry's gun.  It's just a different unit than metric, but the conversion is easy enough.  Doing it by weight is just... odd.

My point was that early on the British recognised that shell weights would vary depending on the type (explosive, incendiary, etc.) and so didn't use the shell weight to classify those weapons.

@ItalianPhilosopher still less odd than bore (gauge) which is still used - a 12-bore shotgun would fit a solid lead ball of 1/12 lb.

@ItalianPhilosopher Weight of the projectile + firepower of the gun = easy calculation (F=m.a; or more precisely a=F/m in this case) for expected range/trajectory. Comparatively, the diameter of the barrel doesn't particularly tell you anything about the range/impact force you'd be expecting. The benefit of knowing the diameter is more related to whoever is making the shells, rather than whoever is trying to use the gun to hit a distant target.

@ChrisH See above comment, if bore is a measure of weight (with an assumed spherical shape), then the same observation applies there.

@Flater That sounds more clever than it actually is, given other complex relationships like propellant charge and barrel length.  And a gunner is not going to rely on this heuristic to know at what range to shoot, they're gonna rely on lot more detailed knowledge about their particular gun's mechanics.

@ItalianPhilosopher The calibers you're talking about are for artillery-style long range attacks, where trajectory calculation was very much part of the process of trying to hit a target. You'll note that this "caliber as weight" tendency doesn't exist for handguns.

No, the guns I am talking about definitely applied to WW2 tank stuff:  the early short barreled 75mm on PzIVs is very different in capabilities from later models, yet presumably has roughly the same weight projectiles.  So, your comment does not really add anything to the question or answers.

@Flater except that bore adds an unnecessary inverse. At least with shell weight a bigger number means bigger. With bore a bigger number means smaller. It's no less silly in things like wire gauge, that works in a similar way

Traditionally, in the age of sail, it used to be just the solid shot.
Later on, this was a nominal designation roughly correlating with one of the projectiles designed for the weapon. The 17-pounder fired 17-lb. "kinetic energy" anti-tank rounds, and the 6-pounder fired 6-lb. KE rounds, in both examples without propellant. The 2-pounder, meanwhile, fired 2.4-lb. KE rounds.

What does "KE round" mean here?

@kimchilover "Kinetic energy", which is a misleading moniker. Many AP rounds have an explosive filler, not relying on kinetic energy alone.

@DevSolar true, but at least some of those were just solid armour-piercing, capped


Is the weight of the projectile constant across shell types?

No, of course not. Take for example the Ordnance QF 6-pounder. Its shells varied from as little as 1.42kg (3 lb 2 oz) for APDS to 3.23kg (7 lb 2 oz) for APCBC. The US fired an even heavier APCBC/HE round, at 3.3kg (7 lb 4 oz). On the other side of the channel, the German 8.8cm (anti-) tank guns of WWII ranged from 7.3kg (APCR) to 10.4kg (APCBC/HE). In either case, there's a number of shells with intermediate weights as well.
The use of "...-pounder" stems back from the Age of Sail, where you would have e.g. a number of 6-pounder, 12-pounder, 24-pounder, and 32-pounder guns to a broadside, depending on ship type. Most of the time these cannons fired solid shot (with chain or grape shot being available options), which was carried to the guns by hand. This made the weight of the shot an important issue.

Cannonballs were also spherical (ignoring chain/grape shot here), meaning there is a direct conversion from weight to barrel size (though not linear, as weight increases by a cube, not linearly). This is assuming the same material is used for all cannonballs and all cannonballs are assumed to be perfect spheres, both of which are reasonable assumptions for that day and age.

@Flater: You mean those were not reasonable assumptions...

During the Age of Sail, variations in production were significant. Because a cannonball getting stuck in the barrel would lead to catastrophic failure; because both bore of the gun and diameter of the cannonball had significant variations; and because the bore of the gun changed during a battle due to heat expansion, cannonballs were made to be smaller than the (nominal) bore of the gun. So wadding was required to actually trap the propellant gasses behind the ball.

the warthunder guys did that research.
With a quick search on their forums I found a reference with weights for different ammo types:
https://forum.warthunder.com/t/british-sub-caliber-ammunition/2822/16

They have a wiki page for their game where ammo types for each vehicle are listed. It may be not always right, but it will give you a basic quick assessment, at least:
https://wiki.warthunder.com/unit/uk_a_34_comet_iron_duke
Cannon QQF mk II: APDS 2.5kg ~ 5.5 pounds ; APBCCS 7.7 ~16.9 pounds ; HE 7kg ~ 15.4pounds
https://wiki.warthunder.com/unit/uk_17_pdr_m10_achilles
Canonon QF-17 : no APDS; 8.4kg (18.5pounds) smoke shell and APBC as above.
you may check their assessment of ammo types and weights for a wide variety of british vehicles:
https://wiki.warthunder.com/ground?v=t&t_c=britain
take care: previously, they researched penetration values for each cannon/ammo which were taken from tables such as given above. Today, penetration values in the game are calculated by a universal formula.
Also, interestingly, the reason that they gave up on 'real' penetration values was that it was too hard to be sure about them. There are too many variations on models of cannons, vehicles, ammo, etc, and way too much variation on penetration experiments and ambiguities in their historical documents. It became too time consuming for them to judge the validity of each reference. So, take everything with a grain of salt, if you want exact numbers.
PS: it looks like some pp get really passionate about historical research when their preferred game appears 'wrong'

Warthunder forums, the best place to search for (sometimes classified) military vehicles/planes data :)

The "poundage" caliber is the nominal weight of a round iron cannonball that could be fired from the gun.  So, an iron cannonball for a 37mm muzzle-loaded smoothbore would weigh about a pound; for a 76mm one, 17 pounds.  Rifled guns carried over this designation even though they were never used to fire roundshot.

Not sure about the math here.  Plugging in 4/3pi radius cubed w density of 7.8 for iron gives about 200g.  Remember that any cylindrical shot will be considerably bigger than a sphere of the same diameter.

I believe the principle changed with the introduction of rifled cannon, and that it was applied inconsistently.
